# "Strip curtain" or "strip curtains"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm translating a Statement of Work for design of a warehouse, and it specifies that a door should have an air curtain and/or **strip curtain**. This strip curtain consists of numerous plastic lamellae:

[image]

Should I use the singular or the plural form to describe it? It consists of numerous elements, but they comprise a single "curtain" so I think I should use the singular form:

> To avoid the inflow of hot air from the street, the door should have an air curtain and/or **strip curtain** made of flexible plastic lamellae.

Comment: Unless there is more than one strip curtain, the singular is correct.

Comment: I haven't seen the Latin plural used there, but **lamellas**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the singular. Unless there is one or more of the strip curtain itself.